# Haskell expression to find free variables (Lambda Calculus)

Tags: haskell, computer-science, lambda-calculus

Given the following definition for a Term:

`data Term = Var String | Application Term Term | Lambda String Term`

How would I extract the free variables in the term to a list?

I'm working with this definition for the expression:

`findVariables :: Term -> [String]`

So far I have this:
`findVariables (Lamda(Var p)(Application z(Lamda(Var q)(Var r)))) = [r]`

The idea is to ignore the variables attached to Lambda () and just take the unattached variables but I'm receiving these errors:

> hw.hs:8:22-26: error:

> • Couldn't match type ‘Term’ with ‘[Char]’
> Expected type: String
> Actual type: Term

> • In the pattern: Var p
> I
> In the pattern:
> Lamda (Var p) (Application z (Lamda (Var q) (Var r)))

> In an equation for ‘findVariables’:
> findVariables
> (Lamda (Var p) (Application z (Lamda (Var q) (Var r))))
> = [r]
> |
> 8 | findVariables (Lamda(Var p)(Application z(Lamda(Var q)(Var r)))) = [r]
> |

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I've updated my question now as per your recommendation. Thank you.

Comment: You use `Lam`, but the data constructor is `Lambda`, so `Lambda (Var q) (Var r)`.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, I've fixed the errors but now I'm receiving couldn't match type errors. I had this problem earlier also before I rewrote the code

Answer (score 1):

`Var` converts a `String` into a `Term` representing the variable of the given name.

But `Lamda` [sic] doesn't take a `Term` as its first argument, it takes the bare `String` that just has the appropriate variable's name. So everywhere you write

```
Lamda (Var foo) bar
```

you should simply write

```
Lamda foo bar
```

instead. This will get you to your next problem (several remain); good luck!